# Any utility function in python which returns value when passed object and attribute to it?

Tags: python

Like we have in Java Beans util where you pass object and the property name it gives you the value do we have anything similar in python:

```
def attr(obj, attr)
    return obj.attr
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getattr` for this purpose. From the [built-in function documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html):

> For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is
>   equivalent to `x.foobar`.